# Is it true that every pseudo-Anosov diffeomorphism is not topologically stable?

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I have received a report on my recent paper and the referee has written that every pseudo-Anosov on a compact smooth manifold is not topologically stable. I don't know the proof. Would you please help me to understand better. Also it is not clear for me definition of pseudo-Anosov and its relation with Anosov diffeomorphism,  but $f:X\to X$ is called topologically stable if for every $\epsilon>0$, there is $\delta>0$ such that if $d(f, g)<\delta$, then there is a continuous map $h:X\to X$ such that $d(h, id_X)<\epsilon$ and $f\circ h= h\circ g$.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Pseudo anosov maps as far as I know are defined only in the case of surface maps. What is your definition of PA maps in higher dimensions?

Comment: Let $S$ be a surface, home. $f:S\to S$ is called a 2-persisten whenever for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that if $d(f, g)<\delta$ and $x\in S$, then there is $y\in S$ with $d(f^{n}(x), g^{n}(y))<\epsilon$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $f$ is $c$- expansive whenever $x\neq y$ then there is $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $d(f^{n}(y), f^{n}(x))>c$

Comment: Referee of my paper said that every psudo Anosov is expansive and 2-persistent but proof of it is not clear for me. Also she/he claimed that every psudo Anosov is not topologically stable. Would you please help me to understand it

Comment: I don't know if this help since probably you already know the related paper by Gerber and Katok, but otherwise you should gain from reading it (also the last short section, with a bit more cryptic cursive information). See: http://www.numdam.org/article/ASENS_1982_4_15_1_173_0.pdf